# Can you declare multiple with variables in a django template?

Tags: python, django

I know it's not good practice, but is there a way to declare multiple variables in a with statement in a django template.

For example I want to do something like this:

```
{% with a="a", b="b", c="c" %}
    {{a}}
    {{b}}
    {{c}}
{% endwith %}
```

**Edit**
My actual use case is this:

```
{% with a,b,c=object|get_abc %}
     {{a}}
     {{b}}
     {{c}}
{% endwith %}
```

**Edit 2**
New Question for first Edit: [Assign multiple variables in a with statement after returning multiple values from a templatetag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925276/assign-multiple-variables-in-a-with-statement-after-returning-multiple-values-fr)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The example on the doc page clearly states that *you can assign more than one variable*, but you wouldn't need those commas:

```
{% with alpha=1 beta=2 %}
    ...
{% endwith %}
```

---

Reference:

[`with` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Comment: You're right. My IDE suggested an error with the above syntax, but it renders just fine. This works.

Comment: On second thought, that wasn't my original use case. My mistake, my actual use case is above.

Comment: @JohnSmith I doubt you can use the `with` tag with another tag. And modifying your question instead of asking a new one is meh!

Comment: What should I do if I want to use the former variable just defined?  `{%with a=3 b=a|add:4%}` does not work.

Comment: @W.Perrin Create a nested `with` statement for `b`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye  Yeah, but  seems  a   little tedious. Is   there   any   better way   to  do  this?

Comment: For anyone who arrived here using Jinja, while Django's templating engine is *very similar* to Jinja2, it is different here and it wants **commas** separating this statement. Otherwise, it is exactly the same.