# Assign multiple variables in a with statement after returning multiple values from a templatetag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to assign multiple variables in a with statement in a django template. I'd like to assign multiple variables in a with statement after returning multiple values from a templatetag

My use case is this:

```
{% with a,b,c=object|get_abc %}
    {{a}}
    {{b}}
    {{c}}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible without a custom templatetag.

However if your method returns always the same length you can do it more compact like this:

```
{% with a=var.0 b=var.1 c=var.2 %}
  ...
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this as allowed, however from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with) multiple assign is allowed.

But you can assign these 3 variables to 1 variable, which will make it `tuple` object, which you can easily iterate by its index.

```
{% with var=object|get_abc %}
  {{ var.0 }}
  {{ var.1 }}
  {{ var.2 }}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not supported and its not a flaw of Django Template Language that it doesn't do that, its Philosophy as stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/):

> Django template system is not simply Python embedded into HTML. This
>   is by design: the template system is meant to express presentation,
>   not program logic

What you could do is prepare your data on Python side and return appropriate format which will be easy to access in template, so you could return a dictionary instead and use dotted notation with key name:

```
{# assuming get_abc returns a dict #}
{% with var=object|get_abc %}
  {{ var.key_a }}
  {{ var.key_b }}
  {{ var.key_c }}
{% endwith %}
```